# How to do custom conversationupdate - new user messaging for each user in Microsoft bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

We are using directlineAPI v3.0 to connect to a custom client application.

We want to show different message / adaptive card greeting message to each user based on their preference.

The custom client application is webchat modified for our purpose. In anonymous channel like webchat, how do we pass a user specific content (based on the user origin website) to the bot?

We have used postactivity event and passed user-id as part of event text.

However due to asynchronous nature of these events, how do we ensure we show bot.on message after we receive postactivity message so that appropriate adaptive card is shown

thanks
srini

Comment: Just to be sure: your custom client interface is using Bot Framework's Webchat project (even customized)? Or a really custom webchat made on your side?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 1):

> However due to asynchronous nature of these events, how do we ensure we show bot.on message after we receive postactivity message so that appropriate adaptive card is shown

You can refer to [Use the backchannel mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel) to achieve this requirement.

In client side

```
var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        domain: params['domain'],
        secret: '<secrect>',
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
      });
botConnection.postActivity({ type: "event", from: user, name: "ConversationUpdate", value: "" }) .subscribe(id => console.log("Conversation updated"));
BotChat.App({
    botConnection: botConnection,
    bot: bot,
    user: user,
    resize: 'detect'
}, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));
```

In server side:

```
bot.on('event',(event)=>{
  console.log(event)
  if(event.name==='ConversationUpdate'){
    bot.beginDialog(event.address, '/');
  }
})
```